# setting cell width with epplus affects the whole column

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I'm having a bit of trouble on solving this. Is there a way to set the width of a specific cell from a worksheet using epplus? Because when i use, for example:

```
ws.Column(1).Width = 40;
```

the whole column gets affected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

As I know, there is no way to change the width of a specific cell. All cells in one column have same width. You can change the width of a cell by merging it with its neighbour. I have an example:

```
sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "This is a cell";
sheet.Cells["A1:A2"].Merge = true;
```

Then you can set width by using

```
sheet.Column(1).Width = 40;
```

or

```
sheet.Cells["A1:A2"].AutoFitColumns();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you  can try like this

```
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("1232");
            ws.Cells["A1"].AutoFitColumns();
            //ws.Cells[""].AutoFitColumns(20);//overloaded 
            //ws.Cells[""].AutoFitColumns(20,40);//overloaded min and max lengths
        }
```